# How use SQL Expressions in @property decorator for async session in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I've got two models **Media** and **Tweet**.
Unfortunately, they don't have a one-to-many relationship. The specifics of the API are: one router sends images (Media), and the other router in the body receives a ids list of images that will be attached to the tweet.

I would like to set a **attachments** field in the Tweet model that would contain a list of paths of attached images, so that later I can simply validate using pydantic schemas.

```
class Media(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'medias'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Sequence('media_id_seq'), primary_key=True, index=True)
    path: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    ....
```

```
class Tweet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tweets'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Sequence('tweet_id_seq'), primary_key=True, index=True)
    content: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(TEXT, nullable=False)
 
    tweet_media_ids: Mapped[list[int]] = mapped_column(ARRAY(Integer), nullable=True)
  
    @property
    def attachments(self):
        if not self.tweet_media_ids:
            return []
        query = select(Media.path).where(Media.id.in_(self.tweet_media_ids))
        result = object_session(self).execute(query)
        return result.scalars().all()
```

I've tried to get a tweet and a list of appended media in attachments, but got  *sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: [https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)*](https://stackoverflow.com) while reffering to item.attachments

```
`@router.get("/tweets", response_model=schemas.TweetsList)
async def get_tweets_list(db: Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(get_db_session)]):
    tweets_orm = await get_tweets(db)
    for item in tweets_orm:
        print("att=", item.attachments)
    tweets = [schemas.Tweet.model_validate(tweet) for tweet in tweets_orm]
    tweets_list = schemas.TweetsList(tweets=tweets)
    return tweets_list`
```

```
172.18.0.3:49338 - "GET /api/tweets HTTP/1.0" 500
 [2023-11-06 05:43:43 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in ASGI application
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
 result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
 return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
 172.18.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2023:05:43:43 +0000] "GET /api/tweets HTTP/1.1" 500 21 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0" "-"
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 292, in __call__
 await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
 await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
 raise exc
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
 await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 83, in __call__
 await self.app(scope, receive, send)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
 raise exc
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
 await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
 raise e
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
 await self.app(scope, receive, send)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
 await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
 await self.app(scope, receive, send)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
 response = await func(request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 273, in app
 raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 190, in run_endpoint_function
 return await dependant.call(**values)
 File "/api/app/routes/tweets.py", line 66, in get_tweets_list
 print("att=", item.attachments)
 File "/api/app/models.py", line 79, in attachments
 result = object_session(self).execute(query)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2306, in execute
 return self._execute_internal(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2188, in _execute_internal
 result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
 result = conn.execute(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1416, in execute
 return meth(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 516, in _execute_on_connection
 return connection._execute_clauseelement(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1639, in _execute_clauseelement
 ret = self._execute_context(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1848, in _execute_context
 return self._exec_single_context(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1988, in _exec_single_context
 self._handle_dbapi_exception(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2346, in _handle_dbapi_exception
 raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1969, in _exec_single_context
 self.dialect.do_execute(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 922, in do_execute
 cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 586, in execute
 self._adapt_connection.await_(
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 116, in await_only
 raise exc.MissingGreenlet(
 sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s)
```

Question:
**how to fix the error or advise another implementation of the attachments field**

Comment: Those console outputs can be copypasted here too.

Comment: It was difficult to do for formatting error

Comment: It doesn't need to be perfect but it allows people to search using ctrl-f and copy paste to better help you.

Comment: I have already fixed it

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [`hybrid_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) instead of `property` decorator.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property  # add this line


class Tweet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tweets'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Sequence('tweet_id_seq'), primary_key=True, index=True)
    content: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(TEXT, nullable=False)
 
    tweet_media_ids: Mapped[list[int]] = mapped_column(ARRAY(Integer), nullable=True)
  
    @hybrid_property
    def attachments(self):
        if not self.tweet_media_ids:
            return []
        query = select(Media.path).where(Media.id.in_(self.tweet_media_ids))
        result = object_session(self).execute(query)
        return result.scalars().all()
```

`sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet` raised by relations might be resolved using `hybrid_property` in your case. The error occurs when manipulating `join` commands in async functions with bad relationships, including lazy loading strategies.

In addition, SQLAlchemy doesn't have to have physical relationships. So you can use `relationship` in your code even if two tables do not have actual relations.

With that:

```py
class Tweet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tweets'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Sequence('tweet_id_seq'), primary_key=True, index=True)
    content: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(TEXT, nullable=False)
 
    medias: Mapped[list[Media]] = relationship(back_populates="medias")
  
    @hybrid_property
    def attachments(self) -> list[Media]:
        return self.medias
```

SQLAlchemy will generate a query with the relationship automatically. In fact, when setting logical relationships, you don't need to write the `attachments` method.

#### Or use [awaitable_attrs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.AsyncAttrs.awaitable_attrs)

You are using `AsyncSession` so that you can use `awaitable_attrs`

```py
@router.get("/tweets", response_model=schemas.TweetsList)
async def get_tweets_list(db: Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(get_db_session)]):
    tweets_orm = await get_tweets(db)
    for item in tweets_orm:
        print("att=", item.awaitable_attrs.attachments)
    tweets = [schemas.Tweet.model_validate(tweet) for tweet in tweets_orm]
    tweets_list = schemas.TweetsList(tweets=tweets)
    return tweets_list
```

`awaitable_attrs` resolves deferred columns that are not loaded yet. It can await `result = await object_session(self).execute(query)` in method `attachments`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    async def get_tweets_list(
        db: Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(get_db_session)]
):
    tweets_orm = await get_tweets(db)
    for item in tweets_orm:
        print("att=", await item.awaitable_attrs.attachments)
    tweets = [schemas.Tweet.model_validate(tweet) for tweet in tweets_orm]
```

It seems item.attachments return coroutine.
await item.awaitable_attrs.attachments return desired list.
So I guess an addition hit to DB is needed. And those query in property decorator does not execute